# Avoid redundant code when having inheritance in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have following base class :

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<T, R>(private val schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider) :
    ViewModel() {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<T>>()
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<T>>
        get() = _liveData

    protected abstract val requestObservable: Observable<R>

    protected abstract fun getSuccessResult(it: R): T

    fun sendRequest() {
        _liveData.value = Resource.Loading()
        composeObservable { requestObservable }
            .subscribe({
                _liveData.postValue(Resource.Success(getSuccessResult(it)))
            }) {
                _liveData.postValue(Resource.Failure(it.localizedMessage))
                Timber.e(it)
            }.also { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
    }
}
```

And here is child class implementation :

```
class MainViewModel(
    api: PokemonService,
    schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider
) : BaseViewModel<List<Pokemon>, List<NamedResponseModel>>(schedulerProvider) {

    override val requestObservable: Observable<List<NamedResponseModel>> =
        api.getPokemonList(LIMIT).map { it.results }

    override fun getSuccessResult(it: List<NamedResponseModel>): List<Pokemon> = it.asDomainModel()

    init {
        sendRequest()
    }
}
```

As you see I put init block in child classes to sendRequest() which is a **redundant**. If I move init block to parent class, it will crash since api is null because init block of parent is called before constructor of child.

Is there any solution to move **sendRequest()** to parent and avoid redundant in child classes?

Source code can be found : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Pokemon

Comment: what do you mean by redundant?

Comment: I have to add init block to sendRequest() in all child classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the design of your inheritance. To get the child items to be executed in the parent's initialization, you need to pass the object to the parent constructor.

Here is an example:

```kotlin
abstract class Base(protected val name: String) {
    init {
        println(name)
    }
}

class CBase(private val s: String) : Base(s) {}

fun main() {
    CBase("Hello");
}
```

In your case, which I haven't tested yet:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseViewModel<T, R>(
    private val schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider,
    protected val requestObservable: Observable<R>):
    ViewModel() {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<T>>()
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<T>>
        get() = _liveData

    protected abstract fun getSuccessResult(it: R): T

    fun sendRequest() {
        _liveData.value = Resource.Loading()
        composeObservable { requestObservable }
            .subscribe({
                _liveData.postValue(Resource.Success(getSuccessResult(it)))
            }) {
                _liveData.postValue(Resource.Failure(it.localizedMessage))
                Timber.e(it)
            }.also { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
    }

    init {
        sendRequest()
    }
}

class MainViewModel(
    api: PokemonService,
    schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider
) : BaseViewModel<List<Pokemon>, List<NamedResponseModel>>(
    schedulerProvider,
    api.getPokemonList(LIMIT).map { it.results }
) {

    override fun getSuccessResult(it: List<NamedResponseModel>): List<Pokemon> = it.asDomainModel()
}
```

Here, you can still access the variable `requestObservable` at the parent's contructor because it is initialized at the constructor parameter, not as an abstract property.

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: I get following exception using your solution : **NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'io.reactivex.Observable se.appshack.android.refactoring.network.PokemonService.getPokemonList(int)' on a null object reference**

Comment: I see. Yeah you are right, my example didn't include passing an object to the child class. Let me try some other idea.